# Read .jar file in Java applet

Tags: java, jar

I have a little Java applet game where you can choose between some themes. It works very well but the downloading time of the huge .jar is not acceptably. Now I want to split the .jar into single .jars, a default one and one for every theme. Now there is just one question: (How) can I read a .jar file from a Java applet which is also a .jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `URLClassLoader`. You can give the URL to the theme.jar as a parameter and use the getResource* methods to access the files inside.

Another approach would be to manually download the JAR and open it with the `java.util.jar` classes, but I would go with the first approach.

Comment: It doesn't work... I get this error: `java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission createClassLoader)`

Comment: This can be a lot of things: Have you signed both jars and access the file on the same server as you originate from?

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I didn't know I have to sign the jars, but now I do :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Deploy the applet using Java Web
   Start.  From Java 1.2 this could be
   done to get a 'free floating' applet
   (outside a web page), but since
   1.6.0_10+, it can also be done for embedded applets.
2. Put each theme in
   a separate Jar and in the JNLP
   (launch file) & mark them as 'lazy'
   download.
3. Notate which package is
   contained in which Jar (also in the
   JNLP file) so the JWS client knows
   which Jar to download for each
   theme. (a)
4. Everything else will work 'like magic', and the JWS client will show a progress bar when downloading the lazy Jars.

(a) For this to work properly, each theme needs to be in a separate package, as well as a separate Jar.

Comment: Oh, you can do the applet thing with webstart now? Nice :) Didn't know.

Comment: @ZeissS  Check out https://jdk6.dev.java.net/plugin2/jnlp/.  I am sure I saw the same document on the Oracle site the other day, but unfortunately cannot find a reference to it at this moment.